# How can I limit longitude and latitude according to their decimal representation range?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I'm writing a Geo-location related software, and I've encountered a problem:
In some point I'm asking the user to enter specific latitude and longitude coordinates - in decimal. My question is how can I limit those fields, so that the user won't be able to enter a number that's not possible?

In other words - what are the ranges of latitude and longitude? When searching this topic I saw an answer in degrees, but I'm interested in the decimal representation, and wasn't sure about the right calculation here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ranges as defined in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/coordinates are:

**latitude:** (approximately)-85 to 85
**longitude:** -180 to 180

You may restrict it by using a HTML5-number-input:

```html
<input type="number" name="longitude" min="-180" max="180" step=".000001">
<input type="number" name="latitude" min="-85" max="85" step=".000001">
```

Answer (score 0):

- Valid latitudes are +90 to -90 degrees.
- Valid longitudes are +180 to -180 degrees (but it is an angle so +/-180 are the same place and  any value can represent a valid longitude).